# How do I sort category results on this code?

Tags: wordpress, categories

I have this code on the category.php file and I need to sort the results by ASC cause right now results are in the reverse order.

Thanks in advance.

```
<ol class="search-results-list">

            <?php 
                // Return Event Items
                $i = 0;
                while (have_posts()) : the_post();

                    if( get_post_type() == 'researcher' ) {
                        $i++; ?>

                        <li><strong><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></strong><br /> <?php print_excerpt(200); ?></li>

                    <?php }

                endwhile;?>

                <?php if( $i == 0 ) { ?><li><?php _e( 'No results were found.', 'qns' ); ?></li><?php } ?>

            <!--END .search-results-list -->
            </ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below code into your functions.php file

```
if ( !function_exists( 'get_cat_id_by_slug' ) ) {
    function get_cat_id_by_slug ($get_slug) {
        $CatId = get_term_by( 'slug', $get_slug, 'category' );
        $CatId = $CatId->term_id;
        return $CatId;
    }
}
```

Add below code into your category.php

```
<?php

    $category_id = get_cat_id_by_slug('researcher');
    $args = 'cat=' . $category_id . 'order=asc';
    query_posts($args);

    if (have_posts()) :

        while (have_posts()) : the_post();
?>  
            <ol class="search-results-list">

                <li>
                    <strong>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                    </strong><br />
                    <?php print_excerpt(200); ?>
                </li>

            </ol>
<?php   
        endwhile;

    else : 
?>
        <ol class="search-results-list">
            <li><?php _e( 'No results were found.', 'qns' ); ?></li>
        </ol>
<?php
    endif;
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much but I'm affraid is not working or there's a kind of conflict. Adding this code turns the whole website completly blank !

Comment: I tested the code and it is working fine. I don't know if it's your custom excerpt or something else is not hooked up properly. @user3489056